# How to interpolate the ConstraintValidator message on a Custom Validation Annotation

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

I've read some Q&As and guides (like [Hibernate Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints-compound)) as to how to work with Hibernate's ConstrainValidator, but none of them mention clearly how to interpolate a value in a **specific position** of a validation error message when creating your own custom validation annotation.

For example, if I have a validation error message that looks like this:

```
foo.bar.error=This value '{myValue}' is wrong.
```

I would like to obtain the following message if the validation fails:

> The value 'some wrong value' is wrong.

The validation would be used like this:

```
public class SomeClass {

    @CustomAnnotation(message="{foo.bar.error}")
    public MyObject myObject;

    ...

}

public class MyObject {
    private String myValue;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've found a way to interpolate the message without much fuzz.

First set your `ValidationMessages.properties` (or wherever your validation messages are stored) as before:

```
foo.bar.error=This value '{wrongValue}' is wrong.
```

Create your annotation like you normally would:

```
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = CustomValueValidator.class)
@Target(FIELD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomAnnotation {    
    String message() default "{foo.bar.error}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Implement your constraint validator like this:

```
import org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorContextImpl;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class CustomValueValidator 
        implements ConstraintValidator<CustomAnnotation, MyObject> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(final CustomAnnotation constraintAnnotation) {
        // Extract any value you would need from the annotation
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final MyObject myObject, 
                           final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        boolean valid;

        // Add your validations over the 'myObject' object

        if (!valid) {
            ((ConstraintValidatorContextImpl) context)
                    .addMessageParameter("wrongValue", myObject.getMyValue());
        }

        return valid;
    }
}
```

Now all that is left is to use the annotation:

```
public class SomeClass {

    // I'm using the default message. You could override it as a parameter
    @CustomAnnotation
    public MyObject anotherObject;

    ...

}
```

Comment: I think `context.unwrap(HibernateConstraintValidatorContext.class)` would be more idiomatic than manually casting to `ConstraintValidatorContextImpl`: `context.unwrap(HibernateConstraintValidatorContext.class).addMessageParameter("wrongValue", simpleDto.toString())`.